# why it's impossible to sort a string just like a sorting of a c++ array?

Tags: c++

can't we sort a string just like a classical sorting(bubble sort or something..) of an array?I tried. But it's not working.

```
string newstr = "dcba";
for(int i = 0; i < (newstr.size())-1; i++)
    {
        for(int k = i+1; k < newstr.size(); k++)
        {
            if(newstr[i] > newstr[k])
            {
                temp = newstr[i];
                newstr[k] = newstr[i];
                newstr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code, statement by statement, in a debugger? What happens with the string when you do?

Comment: This swap is wrong. If you don't know how to implement a swap, just use `std::swap` instead.

Comment: You don't have to write a sorting function yourself, just use `std::sort`.

Comment: Why are you writing a sorting function yourself? Is this homework or assignment?

Comment: *why it's impossible to sort a string*, Why do you assume that the fault is elsewhere when really the fault is that your code is bugged? It's the wrong attitude to have, always assume your code is faulty, otherwise you'll never find the bugs in your code.

Comment: Joining @john: I've been spending hours trying to find a bug in my own (complex) code – just to discover that the library I used actually had a bug. *Twice in > 15 years of experience!* **Hundreds** of times, the error was in my own code. No imagine how much time I would have lost, in contrast, if I would have looked at the libraries first...

Answer (score 3):

The less code you write the less mistakes you make is a good rule to follow. To sort a string you can just do:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string newstr = "dcba";
  std::sort(newstr.begin(), newstr.end());
  std::cout << newstr << "\n";
}
```

The actual bug in your code is due to an incorrect implementation of swap:

```
temp = newstr[i];
newstr[k] = newstr[i];
newstr[i] = temp;
```

Should be:

```
temp = newstr[k];
newstr[k] = newstr[i];
newstr[i] = temp;
```

Or again more simply:

```
std::swap(newstr[i], newstr[k]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not swapping the characters correctly.

Use

```
temp = newstr[k];
```

instead of

```
temp = newstr[i];
```

With your code you are duplicating newstr[i] everywhere, because

```
temp = newstr[i];         // tmp = i
newstr[k] = newstr[i];    // k   = i
newstr[i] = temp;         // i   = tmp = i
```

Answer (score 2):

brush up on your basics . you are running the loop till `newstr.size()-1;` which means you arent considering the last element or reaching it . your's swap logic is also wrong .

modified code -

```
for(int i = 0; i < newstr.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int k = i+1; k < newstr.size(); k++)
        {
            if(newstr[i] > newstr[k])
            {
                std::swap(newstr[i] , newstr[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

you can also do `std::sort(newstr.begin(),newstr.end());`